# Why is ADF failing the SSL handshake with mongodb.net?

Tags: mongodb, ssl, azure-data-factory

For the past few days, we've been getting errors during a daily pipeline run. The errors are similar to this:

> Message:Failure happened on 'Source' side. 
>   ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToConnectOdbcSource,'
>   Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
>   Message= Error from MongoDB Client: No suitable servers found
>   (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set):  TLS handshake failed:
>   error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:
>   certificate verify failed calling ismaster on
>   '.mongodb.net:27017'

I am able to connect to the Mongo database using Mongo CLI. I used Wireshark to confirm the SSL handshake is working fine. It shows that the Mongo cert is issued by ‘Let’s Encrypt' (https://letsencrypt.org/). The ‘Let’s Encrypt’ cert is included in the list of certs and it issued by ‘DST Root CA X3’, which is in the trusted root certs on my computer. Interestingly enough, the Mongo cert was just renewed a few days ago.

Just for fun (see '...verify calling ismaster...' in the message above), in the pipeline configuration, I updated the datasource dataset to ‘Allow Self-Signed Server Cert’ and the connection started working.

I’ll set that flag and allow the pipeline to run a few days to see if it fixes it. But I have no explanation for why this would work other than Azure has a weird way of implementing SSL.

Is there a way to see the list of trusted certs on the Azure server? Is there a way to capture the packets of the SSL handshake on the Azure side?

Comment: After a few days of pipeline runs with ‘Allow Self-Signed Server Cert’ set to true, I no longer see this error. I submitted a support request to Microsoft since this setting is presumably not secure.

Comment: Hi, appreciate to your sharing.If you get any response from MS,please post here as an answer to end this case,thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft suggested I upgrade the MongoDB Collection dataset type to MongoDB Collection V2. The pipeline I was working with had been developed a while back. The V2 version does not have 'Allow Self-Signed Server Cert'. This turned out to work for me though.